# Gensim & Keras preprocessing text:how to eliminate punctuation when using text_to_word_sequence function

Tags: python, nlp, keras, word2vec

I use filter like this:

```
text_to_word_sequence(line,filters='!”#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?
@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n\r？！。，“')
```

to eliminate punctuation 
but when I check the performance of gensim word2Vec

```
model.most_similar('country')
```

I got

```
[('nation', 0.8125789761543274),
 ('country,', 0.7982310056686401),
 ('country.', 0.6794269680976868),
 ('region', 0.667543351650238),
 ('continent', 0.6630430221557617),
 ('countries', 0.6313810348510742),
 ('territory', 0.6307457685470581),
 ('nation,', 0.6306755542755127),
 ('britain', 0.6112251281738281),
 ('india', 0.6077225208282471)]
```

It seems that not all the punctuation is eliminated,why?